# validation for Us phone format

Tags: jquery

We are implementing us phone format in our application.but that format allows all zeros like [(000) 000-0000] this.We want the regex format which should not allow the all zeros.
             So,anyone can please respond to my question.

Comment: Your application is build with? You want the regex format for US phone format validation? What have you tried so far? What is your expectation on this question? Should someone post the regex?

Comment: I think if you already have a regex and supports the length and format just you want to validate if it is a valid phone number or not. There you can add a specific case for all 0's all 1's all 2's etc. Then again how would you stop 123-456-7890 not sure thats valid..

Comment: we tried this so far.

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("PhoneUS", function (value, element) {
        var i = /^(\(([0-9]{3})\)[ ]([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4}))$/;
        return this.optional(element) || (i.test(value) > 0);
    }, "Invalid Phone number");

Comment: Try using `autoNumeric.js` library.